# Unable to connect to mongodb when running express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to programming and am currently learning MEAN. Basically I am getting the following error message below when trying to run nodemon server from home. This problem does not happen when I'm at school or at my local Starbucks. Can someone please take a look at the following error I'm getting [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost localhost:27017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou4bK.png) and help me understand why I can't connect to mongoDB? For clarification, yes I do have mongod running on a separate terminal. I am running macOS High Sierra -v 10.13.4 on a 2011 macbook pro. Please help me. Thank you.

Here's the error I get when starting my server:

> [nodemon] starting `node server`
>
> (node:27636) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>
> listening on port 8000
>
> (node:27636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost localhost:27017]
>       at Pool.
>
> (/Users/ROBONYX21/Desktop/Angular/product_list/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
>
> at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
>      at Connection. >(/Users/ROBONYX21/Desktop/Angular/product_list/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
>      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
>      at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
>      at Socket. >(/Users/ROBONYX21/Desktop/Angular/product_list/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
>      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
>      at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>
> (node:27636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:27636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

This is what's showing on the terminal running mongod [mongod port 27017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzJWZ.png)

```
2018-11-22T09:48:15.268-0800 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-11-22T09:48:20.581-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000

2018-11-22T09:48:22.917-0800 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'

2018-11-22T09:48:23.545-0800 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Here is my node.js file in which I'm connecting to the mongoose db.
[mongoose.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77jr6.png)

Comment: can you turn off your antivirus (if any) and firewall also can you attach your nodejs file where you're making connection.

Comment: You are being asked for code which is "text". Not a picture. And you were given a warning when you attempted to add the picture exactly for that reason. Copy the text of the code into your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)